# How can I connect to a database server within a VPN via Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-data-factory

There is a ORACLE database that is only accessible within the context of a VPN.
I would like to connect to this database using Data Factory, for example.

When I try to connect, it says that the server is not reachable. I believe it is because of the VPN.

How can I configure Azure Portal to create a connection to this VPN? Is it possible?

Comment: Which database, sql server, mysql or others, on-premise or in VM?

Comment: Hello Leon Yue. It is an Oracle database on-premise.

Comment: When we access the on-premise source from Data Factory, we must need the self-host integration runtime. You could first try this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle

Comment: Hi @Aleix, did you try this?

Comment: Did you try the link?

Comment: Hello everyone. This situation was solved using a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime properly set up. I used one that the company had already configurated. Thanks for you attention. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime

Comment: @Aleix You're welcome, we're glad to help you. Congratulations the the issue is resolved now. I post it as answer, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we want to access the on-premise source from Data Factory, we must need the self-host integration runtime.

And congratulations that the situation was solved:

"This situation was solved using a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime properly set up. I used one that the company had already configurated. "

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime